# Mapbox GL custom control apply custom style

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, mapbox-gl

For the website `Angular 8`, `Typescript` and `SCSS` are used. 
To display a map `mgl-map` is used.
Now i wanted to create a custom control for it and apply custom styles to it.

I add it to the map using:

```
  const centerOnCoordinatesControl = new CenterOnCoordinatesControl();
  this.mapBoxMap.addControl(centerOnCoordinatesControl, 'bottom-left');
```

which works fine but my custom styles don't get applied to the custom control.

[image: Icon without style]

To check if the css styles get loaded at all i created the same element outside the map control:

[image]

**location.component.html:**

```
<mgl-map class="mapbox-map"
         [style]="defaultStyle"
         [zoom]="zoom"
         [center]="grazCoord"
         (click)="onMapClick($event)"
         (load)="mapLoaded($event)">
         <mgl-control mglScale unit="metric" position="bottom-right"></mgl-control>
         <mgl-control *ngIf="this.mapBoxMap" mglFullscreen position="top-right"></mgl-control>
         <mgl-control *ngIf="this.mapBoxMap" mglGeolocate position="top-right"></mgl-control>
</mgl-map>
```

**location.component.ts:**

*CustomControl:*

```
class CenterOnCoordinatesControl {
  private map: any;
  private container: HTMLDivElement; 

  onAdd(map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.container = document.createElement('div');
    const control = document.createElement('i');

    control.className = 'custom-center-control mapboxgl-ctrl fas fa-map-marker-alt pointer'; 

    this.container.appendChild(control);
    return this.container;
  } 
}
```

**location.component.scss:**

```
.custom-center-control {
    font-size: x-large;
    color: green;

    &:hover {
        color: $cities-orange-light;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the style gets applied to the one outside the map but not to that CustomControl inside the map.

How can i make it work?

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the encapsulation method add this `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
 to your decorator :

Example :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-input',
  templateUrl: 'src/my-custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls:['src/my-custom-input.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```